# OpenFileDialog hide preview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a strange situation where I have an rtf file, that while it opens in word, if I select it in an openfiledialog, then it freezes my .NET app and i have to kill the WINWORD.exe process to regain functionality. This is an issue with the preview pane as when it is hidden, there is no problem.

My call to openfiledialog is bog standard.

```
using (OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog() { Title = "Select document...", CheckFileExists = true, Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*" })
{
    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) _FileName = openDialog.FileName;
    else return;
}
```

Other files preview OK, though I anticipate there may be other files may cause a problem, I just haven't found them yet.

As i doubt I can troubleshoot the actual dialog, my workaround is to disable the preview pane - is there any way to do this? of prevent it showing by default?

This is a problem whether the app is run in debug, or standalone.

Comment: Please don't tack " .NET c#" on to the end of your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 6):

Use the old Windows 95/98 version of the OpenfileDialog that does not have a Preview pane.

To do this, set the `openDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled` parameter to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

try using the function `Dispose()` of `openDialog` before you use rtf file on your code.

Comment: he is using the using-statement, so Dispose of the OpenFileDialog gets called

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe that there is much that you can do about this, other than file a bug report with Microsoft.